# How to update EngineContext.Current.Resolve<StoreInformationSettings>().ResponsiveDesignSupported after upgrade to nopcommerce 3.9

Tags: c#, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90

We try to upgrade an existing nopcommerce application from 3.40 to 3.90.

All steps from http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/Upgrading+nopCommerce are followed.

In all web.config files from custom Themes and Custom Plugins The MVC version is updated from `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0,` to `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0`.

Now we get the folowing error in our custom Theme.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'Nop.Core.Domain.StoreInformationSettings' does not contain a definition for 'ResponsiveDesignSupported' and no extension method 'ResponsiveDesignSupported' accepting a first argument of type 'Nop.Core.Domain.StoreInformationSettings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

There seems to be no ResponsiveDesignSupported property in the StoreInformationSettings.

Is there a way in nopcommerce 3.90 to get the `ResponsiveDesignSupported` setting?

Below some code

```
@model TopMenuModel
@using Nop.Core.Domain
@using Nop.Core.Infrastructure
@using Nop.Web.Models.Catalog;
@{
    var isRtl = this.ShouldUseRtlTheme();
    var supportResponsive = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<StoreInformationSettings>().ResponsiveDesignSupported;
}
@helper RenderCategoryLine(CategorySimpleModel category, int level, bool responsiveMobileMenu)
{
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = category.SeName    })">@category.Name
        @if (category.NumberOfProducts.HasValue)
        {
            <text> </text>@T("Categories.TotalProducts", category.NumberOfProducts.Value)
        }
        </a>
        @{
            var levelClass = "";
            if (level == 0)
            {
                levelClass = "firstLevel";
                <div class="top-menu-triangle"></div>
            }
            if (category.SubCategories.Count > 0)
            {
                if (responsiveMobileMenu)
                {
                    <span class="expand">&nbsp;</span>
                }
                <div class="sublist @levelClass">
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var subCategory in  category.SubCategories)
                    {
                        @RenderCategoryLine(subCategory, level + 1, responsiveMobileMenu)
                    }
                </ul>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </li>
}

<ul class="top-menu">
    @Html.Widget("header_menu_before")
    @if (Model.Categories.Count > 0)
    {
        <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("HomePage")"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"> </i></a></li>
        foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
        {
            @RenderCategoryLine(category, 0, false)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //no categories to display? in this case let's diplay some default menu items (should we?)
        <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("HomePage")">@T("HomePage")</a></li>
        if (Model.RecentlyAddedProductsEnabled)
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("RecentlyAddedProducts")">@T("Products.NewProducts")</a>
            </li>
        }
        <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ProductSearch")">@T("Search")</a>         </li>
        <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("CustomerInfo")">@T("Account.MyAccount")</a></li>
        if (Model.BlogEnabled)
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Blog")">@T("Blog")</a></li>
        }
        if (Model.ForumEnabled)
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Boards")">@T("Forum.Forums")    </a></li>
        }
        <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ContactUs")">@T("ContactUs")</a></li>
    }
    @Html.Widget("header_menu_after")
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('li', '.top-menu').on('mouseenter', function () {
        $('a', $(this)).first().addClass('hover');
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('top-menu')) {
            var width = $(this).innerWidth();
            $('.sublist', $(this)).first().css('@(isRtl ? "right" : "left")', width + 15);
        }
        $('.sublist', $(this)).first().addClass('active');
        $('.top-menu-triangle', $(this)).addClass('active');
    });

    $('li', '.top-menu').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $('a', $(this)).first().removeClass('hover');
        $('.sublist', $(this)).first().removeClass('active');
        $('.top-menu-triangle', $(this)).removeClass('active');
    });

    </script>

@if (supportResponsive)
{
    <div id="mob-menu-button">
        <a href="">
            <span class="icon"><span class="line"></span><span class="line"></span><span class="line"></span></span>
            @{
                var responsiveMenuTitle = Model.Categories.Count > 0 ? T("Categories") : T("Menu");
            }
            <span>@responsiveMenuTitle</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="mob-top-menu">
        @Html.Widget("mob_header_menu_before")
        @if (Model.Categories.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
            {
                @RenderCategoryLine(category, 0, true)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //no categories to display? in this case let's diplay some default menu items (should we?)
            <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("HomePage")">@T("HomePage")</a></li>
            if (Model.RecentlyAddedProductsEnabled)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("RecentlyAddedProducts")">@T("Products.NewProducts")</a>
                </li>
            }
            <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ProductSearch")">@T("Search")</a> </li>
            <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("CustomerInfo")">@T("Account.MyAccount")</a></li>
            if (Model.BlogEnabled)
            {
                <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Blog")">@T("Blog")</a></li>
            }
            if (Model.ForumEnabled)
            {
                <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Boards")">@T("Forum.Forums")    </a></li>
            }
            <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ContactUs")">@T("ContactUs")</a></li>
        }
        @Html.Widget("mob_header_menu_after")
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('a', $('#mob-menu-button')).toggle(function() {
                $('.mob-top-menu').addClass('show');
            },
            function() {
                $('.mob-top-menu').removeClass('show');
            }
        );

        $(function($) {
            $('.mob-top-menu .expand').click(function() {
                var parent = $(this).parent();
                if (parent.hasClass('active')) {
                    $(".sublist:first", parent).hide(300);
                    parent.removeClass('active');
                } else {
                    $(".sublist:first", parent).show(300);
                    parent.addClass('active');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: What other properties do you have access to? Could you show some code?

Comment: @DavidG I've added code

Comment: Hmm I think this option has just been removed as there is no way to disable responsiveness now. Makes sense really as everything should just be responsive.

Comment: @DavidG thanks for your help. I will remove all responsiveSupported checks in the custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

since version 3.70 the ResponsiveDesignSupported setting is no longer available, and nop supports responsive themes out of the box, if you want to turn off or turn on responsive designs in a theme, it should be done inside your theme itself by jquery, css.

Answer (score -1):

Responsive design supported option is removed from nopCommerce 3.6 onward.

If you have purchased a custom theme from any vendor please get the theme for your nopCommerce 3.9 version.